# JS loads images after page load and calculates space wrongly

Tags: javascript, image, overlap

I have a website (flamencosrosas.com), run with WP and the Gridly template. I've noticed the images will overlap on the very first page load. If I refresh the page it won't happen again. My colleague told me this happens because images are being loaded after the page loads, which is why the JS code is calculating the image height wrongly and why they overlap.

I know nothing about JS and am unable to solve this issue. Could someone possibly help, please?

Many thanks! :)

Comment: You should declare your image height and width in html so you don't have any JS : <img width="100" height="100" /> : this way the image already have a width/height at load.

Comment: any answer given would be, at best, a wild guess of the problem. replicate the issue using as less code as possible, and post the code here please.